# Javascript:: click is working (only if it's not a new window or tab)?

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, href, getelementbyid

Javascript `click()` event working perfectly but only if the link is not a new window or tab...

**Working example :**

```
<a href="http://puaction.com" id="new">Visit PUACTION</a>

<script>
document.getElementById('new').click();
</script>
```

**But this is not working (add : target="_blank") :**

```
<a href="http://puaction.com" id="new" target="_blank">Visit PUACTION</a>

<script>
document.getElementById('new').click();
</script>
```

What is it about open a new tab (or window) that reject the click event and how do I solve it ?

Comment: Possibly the browser’s popup blocker at work, because it as attempted to open a new window without user interaction.

Comment: ...Is there any solution for that ?

Comment: I could not reproduce this. There my be interference from a third party program or service (Ad-Blocker or something like that).

Comment: For what actual _problem_? (Read: What are you actually trying to _achieve_ here?) If you are attempting to “trick” a user’s popup blocker, then _hopefully_ the answer is No, otherwise the blocker would not be doing its job.

Comment: If user open an article it's better to open a new tab/window instead of replace the existing content... :) Should be an easy solution for that...

Comment: sure, have user click on a link. Browser will accept that

Comment: I want to put an advertisement for 5 second that is why under js

Comment: You need to be more specific … where do you want to put that ad, how is it supposed to work, …

Comment: settimeout ad and then redirect to the new window without closing the current one...

Comment: Maybe you could display the ad in the newly opened page instead, f.e. as an overlay for a couple of seconds.